# Stream android logcat output to an sd card

Tags: android, file, sd-card, logcat

I want to achieve the following but so far, no luck

- Open a file in the SD Card when the android application first started.
- Stream the logcat output to the file.
- When the application exits, stop the logcat streaming.

In my ApplicationClass extends Application onCreate() method, I do this

```
wwLogManager.openLogFile();
```

and here's the code in the openLogFile()

```
        private static final String LOGCAT_COMMAND = "logcat -v time -f ";
        String timestamp = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String logFileName = BuildConstants.LOG_LOCATION + "_" + timestamp + ".log";                    
        mLogFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + logFileName);
        mLogFile.createNewFile();
        String cmd = LOGCAT_COMMAND + mLogFile.getAbsolutePath();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

I do get log files in the sd card, but the log output in these files do not have any trace of the Log.i() calls that I placed in my activities. Is the logcat command that I used here correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I ended up using the BufferedReader to read the output from the Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).

Comment: Can you post an answer here that shows exactly what you did, for mine and all others benefit?

Comment: @JPM: Please see the answer that I just posted...

Answer (score 6):

I apologize if I am misunderstanding your goals, but perhaps you could use the [java.util.logging API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) instead of using Logcat or the Android Logging mechanism.

Like the Android logging API, the [java.util.logging API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) allows you to easily log messages at various levels, such as FINE, FINER, WARN, SEVERE, etc.

But the standard logging API has additional advantages, too.  For example, you can easily create a log *file* by using a [FileHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html).  In fact, [FileHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) has a built-in log rotation mechanism, so you don't have to worry (so much) about cleaning up the log files.  You can also create a hierarchy of [Logger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html)s; so, for example, if you have two [Logger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html)s, *com.example.foo* and *com.example.foo.bar*, changing the logging level of the former will also change the logging level of the latter.  This will even work if the two [Logger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html)s are created in different classes!  Moreover, you change logging behavior at runtime by specifying a logging configuration file.  Finally, you can customize the format of the log by implementing your own [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html) (or just use the [SimpleFormatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) to avoid the default XML format).

To use the standard logging API, you might try something like this:

```
    // Logger logger is an instance variable
    // FileHandler logHandler is an instance variable

    try {
        String logDirectory =
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/log_directory";

        // the %g is the number of the current log in the rotation
        String logFileName = logDirectory + "/logfile_base_name_%g.log";

        // ...
        // make sure that the log directory exists, or the next command will fail
        // 

        // create a log file at the specified location that is capped 100kB.  Keep up to 5 logs.
        logHandler = new FileHandler(logFileName, 100 * 1024, 5);
        // use a text-based format instead of the default XML-based format
        logHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        // get the actual Logger
        logger = Logger.getLogger("com.example.foo");
        // Log to the file by associating the FileHandler with the log
        logger.addHandler(logHandler);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        // do something wise
    }

    // examples of using the logger
    logger.finest("This message is only logged at the finest level (lowest/most-verbose level)");
    logger.config("This is an config-level message (middle level)");
    logger.severe("This is a severe-level message (highest/least-verbose level)");
```

The Android logging mechanism is certainly easy and convenient.  It isn't very customizable, though, and log filtering must be done with tags, which can easily become unwieldy.  By using the [java.uitl.logging](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) API, you can avoid dealing with a multitude of tags, yet easily limit the log file to specific parts of your application, gain greater control over the location and appearance of the log, and even customize logging behavior at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! My goal is to have the Android logcat trace in a file, so I can trace the events related to my app. Do you know if the java.util.logging will include Android stacktrace in there. For example, when the app force close, does it log the crash trace?

Comment: @Michael - If you app crashes, then it should do so via an exception. The java.util.logging method allows you to log exceptions.  See the [Logger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#throwing%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) method for more information.

Comment: Is this not going to slow down the application? it is just an android phone after all and with limited resources. writing to a file can be a costly process. Right?

Comment: @Enigma: Yes, but under the extreme condition when you needed to log a long running operation, this util could be useful. I don't envision we need it all the time though.

Answer (score 4):

I repost my answer here so @JPM and others can see... The code basically just execute the logcat command and then build the log from the input stream.

```
final StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
try {        
    ArrayList<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<String>();
    commandLine.add("logcat");
    commandLine.add("-d");
    ArrayList<String> arguments = ((params != null) && (params.length > 0)) ? params[0] : null;
    if (null != arguments){
        commandLine.addAll(arguments);
    }

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine.toArray(new String[0]));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){ 
        log.append(line);
        log.append(LINE_SEPARATOR); 
    }
} 
catch (IOException e){
        //
} 

return log;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try manually setting a filter as described here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html#filteringOutput

Something like:

```
logcat ActivityManager:I MyApp:V *:S
```

If you replace "MyApp" with the log tags that you are using, that should show you all info (and greater) logs from ActivityManager, and all verbose (and greater) logs from your app.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the filter

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer to the question but I would highly recommend using [Logback](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/) to write messages to a log file as well as the logcat.

1. Copy [logback-android-1.0.10-2.jar](https://bitbucket.org/tony19/logback-android-jar/downloads/logback-android-1.0.10-2.jar) and [slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar) to your libs folder.
2. Right-Click on both libs and from the menu select Build Path -> Add to Build Path.
3. Create a logback.xml file in your assets folder and enter the following:

```
  

  
  
    
      %msg
    
  

  
  
    
      WARN
    

    ${LOG_DIR}/log.txt

    
      %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
```

1. To write a log:

   public class MyActivity extends Activity
   {
       public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyActivity.class);

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle b)
   {
       super(b);
       try{
           throw new Exception("Test");
       }catch(Exception e){
           logger.error("Something bad happened",e);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: I honestly couldn't get this to format correctly. But you can see the code if you click on edit.