# How to write entire Logcat in to sdcard?

Tags: android, logcat

I need to write entire Logcat in to sdcard not the filtered Logcat. So I tried doing this way

```
String[] cmd  ={"/system/bin/logcat " +"-f"+" /sdcard/d.txt"};
    Log.d("NTK","cmd string"+cmd);
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();

    Process pr;
    try {
        pr = run.exec(cmd);

    pr.waitFor();
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        Log.i(NTL, "lines"+line);
    }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have given all permissions in manifest file too.

Not able to  write logcat in to sdcard.

Comment: Please find the similar Question for this :[LogCat on SDCard][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970169/stream-android-logcat-output-to-an-sd-card

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: i have solved the issue buy executing "/system/bin/logcat -b main -f /sdcard/logcat.txt" .Here  '-b main ' allows you to select alternate logcat buffers i.e(main,radio,events).-f pipelines the logcat buffer to sdcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have [`this`](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically) Tutorial for Reading the Logs. And for writing the logs in the file you can simply use `FileWriter` give path of the file with file name.

```
try {
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            if (root.canWrite()) {
                File gpslogfile = new File(root, "log.txt");
                FileWriter gpswriter = new FileWriter(gpslogfile, true);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(gpswriter);
                out.append(DataToWrite);
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Log: ", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
        }
```