# How to export android Log?

Tags: android, logging, logcat

I need to export the log that my application create, there is a way to do that?

or at least there is a way to get all the log written by my application?

edit: i need to do that directly on my application.

**Edit: solved using this guide 

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically**

Comment: see related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21841304/2399024

Answer (score 0):

If you use are using a linux machine you can run something like this

adb logcat org.myorg.myapp > LOG
or 
adb logcat | grep org.myorg > LOG

Comment: sorry i just edited the answer, i need to export the log using my application