# Logging things that happend in android by specific package name

Tags: android, android-logcat

I'm after a solution for a heavy logging mecanism, to log out what happens when for instance an `ANR` occurs at a specific packagename. What I want to achieve, is to log the information `LogCat` outputs when the phone is connected to the computer. **Is this possible to do when the phone is disconnected and in use by a "regular" user?**

I've found this great [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570458/periodic-logcat-polling-for-updates-and-saving-to-sdcard), which outputs som relevent logcat stuff to a text file on the sdcard.

I've used the command: `logcat -b main -d -v time` as the string parameter to for sorting logging.

I also found a possbile solution by expanding the command to sort after Level(`DEBUG`, `VERBOSE`, `ERROR` ETC).

So the command would look something like this:

```
adb -d logcat com.my.package:E *:S
```

I found this command at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android), but it wouldnt't log out anything to my file.

**So my questions is:**

How can I, based on the information above, log out the logcat information, by level `ERROR`, to a `.txt` file on the phones sdcard, without having the phone connected to the computer and eclipse. Is it possible at all?

Many Thanks!

Comment: It is not possible as of Android 4.1, unless the package name is your own app. http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html

Comment: I only want to log out information that my application outputs.

Comment: Then why are you bothering with all this undocumented crap? Just wrap your `Log.d()` and kin calls in something that also logs them to your own file. There are tons of Java logging frameworks, some of which will work on Android, one of which (java.util.logging) is baked into Android.

Answer (score 0):

After a long trial and error I found solution, hope this helps others. To write application specific log to text file in sd card use this command.

```
"logcat -b main -d -v time ['your package name will go here']".
```