# Writing logcat messages in sd card on crash

Tags: android

I am developing an android app. My app gets crashed often. I want to save the logcat messages in sd card while the apps gets crashed to find the root cause. Is ther any way to do this?

Comment: Is this just for local debugging, or do you want something that can be shipped with the app?

Comment: You may be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378550/android-crash-reporting-library-pre-froyo and also take a look around at ACRA and other solutions.  If you need to ship it you will need a pretty scary "read sensitive log data" permission.

Comment: I need it for local debugging

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas which might help you step toward fully automated crash log gathering.  We have yet to roll a full system here, we've had enough luck with just grabbing devices after they've crashed or asking for more info from our QA group, but:

- [ACRA](http://acra.ch) is relatively easy to implement, and even if you don't implement it, the source is on github for you to poke around in.
- The related question [Android crash reporting library (pre Froyo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378550/android-crash-reporting-library-pre-froyo?lq=1) has a number of links and solutions, including [android-remote-stacktrace](http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/), the aforementioned ACRA, [Android-Error-Reporter](https://github.com/tomquist/Android-Error-Reporter), and other commercial solutions.
- Some devices capture the crash output automatically, you can grab it via `adb pull /data/log/dumpstate_app_native.txt.gz` or similar -- the paths should appear in logcat.  These tend to be overwritten with each crash, though.  (If anyone can answer whether this is a manufacturer-specific feature or something that appeared in some version of android's core, I'd love to know!)
- You can get a logcat app, e.g. [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en) or many others, that you can install on your device.
- [TestFlight](https://www.testflightapp.com/) is going into beta on Android side; they have crash reporting on the iOS side and should on the Android side too, and there are various other lovely benefits to using their services -- and integration is really easy in our experience.

If you're rolling your own inside your app, you need the [READ_LOGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_LOGS) and [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) manifest permissions (even for local builds), then you can use the logging API or a regular File.copy or even a system call off to `logcat` itself.  There are a bunch of options and examples in the "Related" links to the side of this question:

- [Stream android logcat output to an sd card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970169/stream-android-logcat-output-to-an-sd-card?rq=1)
- [How to redirect my log output from logcat to the SD-Card on an android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359692/how-to-redirect-my-log-output-from-logcat-to-the-sd-card-on-an-android-device?rq=1)
- ...and so on.

Hopefully this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your own logcat messages is covered by other questions.

[how can i access logcat file on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417389/how-can-i-access-logcat-file-on-device)
[Read logcat programmatically within application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application)

In order to do this when your app crashes you need to install an defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler.

Either on your activity on create or your application on create. Add the following code.

```
        final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler oldUncaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
            // DO your error handling here. 
            //  Write your log cat, or write your exception stack trace here. 

            // Get rid of this line if you don't want a popup letting you know that your app has crashed. 
            oldUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread,throwable);
        }
    });
```